# Play video when scrolled to, BUT play video ONCE

Tags: javascript, html, video

I want to adapt a code I found at http://jsfiddle.net/jAsDJ/. It is almost what I need, except I want the video to play only once. The code found in the link above plays on scroll even after taking out the loop attribute on the video tags.

At http://jsfiddle.net/duya0ntw/1/  you can see what I did: Added JS line 4, lines 23-26 and lines 34-38. I was trying to create a function to determine whether the video had been played at full length and play only when the video had not been played.

Below is the JS. Any help would be greatly appreciated. I have been messing with it for a few hours with no luck. (very novice with JS)

---

```
var videos = document.getElementsByTagName("video"), fraction = 0.8;
var once = new Array(videos.length);

function checkScroll() {

for (var i = 0; i < videos.length; i++) {

    var video = videos[i];

    var x = video.offsetLeft,
        y = video.offsetTop,
        w = video.offsetWidth,
        h = video.offsetHeight,
        r = x + w, //right
        b = y + h, //bottom
        visibleX, visibleY, visible;

    visibleX = Math.max(0, Math.min(w, window.pageXOffset + window.innerWidth - x, r - window.pageXOffset));
    visibleY = Math.max(0, Math.min(h, window.pageYOffset + window.innerHeight - y, b - window.pageYOffset));
    visible = visibleX * visibleY / (w * h);

        if (visible > fraction) {
            if (once[i] == false) {
                video.play();
                once[i] = true;
                }
            } 
        else {
        //video.pause();
    }
}
}

$(document).ready(function () {
for (var i = 0; i < videos.length; i++) {
    once[i] = false;
}
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change:

```
if (visible > fraction)
```

to:

```
if (visible > fraction && video.currentTime < video.duration)
```

That way your videos will not loop - they will only play if the playhead isn't already at the end.

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/jAsDJ/218/

And here is [the reference I used to construct this answer](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_av_dom.asp), which might be helpful.